# It is possible to create a custom landing page in Liferay?

Tags: liferay

It is possible to create a landing page in Liferay? If so, in which version? And how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be achieve this the following way :

1. Make a page (just a normal liferay page) and remember the friendly url.
2. Set the appropiate permissions depending on your senario
3. Go to the control panel
4. In the portal section - click portal settings
5. You can set the Friendly url under the navigation part (located in center of screen)

[image]

These steps are for Liferay 6.1.0 CE.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying liferay to use a landing page was there from version 5. You can also set this using properties file. Create (if you have not done before) a portal-ext.properties file in webapp/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes folder with these lines modified according to you.

```
##
## Default Landing Page
##

#
# Set the default landing page path for logged in users relative to the
# server path. This is the page users are automatically redirected to after
# logging in. For example, if you want the default landing page to be
# http://localhost:8080/web/guest/login, set this to /web/guest/login. To
# activate this feature, set auth.forward.by.last.path to true. To customize
# the behavior, see com.liferay.portal.events.DefaultLandingPageAction in
# the "login.events.post" property above.
#
default.landing.page.path=
#default.landing.page.path=/web/guest/login
```